# What is the scope of SPContext.Current.Web.GetList?

Tags: list, document-library, visual-web-part, web

In my visual web part for sharepoint 2010, I use the function `SPContext.Current.Web.GetList("myserverrelativeurl")` to get a document library. But I noticed this only works if the link is in the same site as the web part. If I try a link to a document library from a child site or parent site, it will give an error with the stacktrace:

```
(7/12/2013 12:17:08 PM) - Error Message: Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070001)
Stacktrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl(String bstrUrl, Int32 METADATAFLAGS, Guid& pgListId, Int32& plItemId, Int32& plType, Object& pvarFileOrFolder)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetList(String strUrl)
```

Is this normal behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is normal behavior. `SPContext.Current.Web` will only allow you to access lists from the current site.

Before you access an outside list, you must open the `SPWeb` object of the site which contains the list.

Example:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("url/of/child/or/parent/site")
{
    using(SPWeb web = new site.OpenWeb())
    {
       SPList list = web.GetList("myserverrelativeurl");

       //rest of the code related to the web object.
    }
}
```

Comment: If I open a site and web using the using tag, then get the library object,  then save the library object to a global variable. Then let the site and web be disposed from the using tags, can I still get items from that library object?

Comment: Ideally, you should do all the operations on the items inside the using blocks. However, in special cases I suggest you use the SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable() method which returns a DataTable object containing the items. You can save that in a global variable and re-use it after the using blocks are closed too.